# Windows container with ASP.Net MVC, IIS NOT displaying the fonts correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, iis, windows-server-2016

I have launched a container from the base image Microsoft\aspnet for my ASP.Net MVC application which uses 4.5 version of .Net framework.

However, when I fire it up, I don't see the fonts being rendered (woff, ttf). From what I've read, the older versions of IIS need a mapping for the MIME types of those fonts; however, since the container is using version 10 of IIS, I am wondering why the fonts are not being displayed correctly?

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: What’s happening For those fonts? are you getting a 404? Or something else?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: It gives 500.19 error